# Rails How to send an Authenticity Token in an Ajax Request without a form involved?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, authenticity-token

For several reasons I need to send a post request to a controller via Ajax and I can't do it involving a form, it has to be a JS Ajax request written inside a file in assets > javascript or between  tags.

I've written a function which seems to pass data correctly. However, it isn't passing a valid Authenticity Token, hence not allowing the request to go through.

Is there a way to comply with CSRF protection generating a token so the controller is happy with it?

**So far my Ajax function is:**

```
  var functionOne = function() {
  var $form = $('#'  + tinyMCE.activeEditor.formElement.id);
  var action = $form.attr('action')
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: action,
    data: $form.serialize(),
    dataType: 'script',
  });
};
```

**This form is passing the following params**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "open_ender"=>
  {"answer_id"=>"4",
  "content"=>"<p>testing text</p>"},
  "id"=>"5"}
```

**I've tried including the following line inside the Ajax object**

```
authenticity_token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
```

**and this in the application layout head without success**

```
$(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({
  headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
  });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Appart from Aniket's solution. Adding

```
authenticity_token: true
```

in the form options hash solved the issue as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just pass a hidden field with value of authenticity token inside of your form and that should work.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :authenticity_token, value: form_authenticity_token %>
```

OR

```
<input type=hidden name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">
```

Comment: Hi Aniket, thanks it works. Although I'm using simple form I added the line above and Rails stopped complaining. However, now it's blaming about  **ActionController::UnknownFormat**. This is strange since the form is set to remote: true and my controller is responding with JS and it works if I submit the form with the submit button. Any clues on what would be the issue.

Comment: By the way it seems that the issue CSRF issue is as well resolved by adding authenticity_token: true in the form's options hash. It may be something about the way tinyMCE works that is interfering  with Rails default of creating an authenticity token. Clearly I'm too ignorant to know what the hell is happening!

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the below:

  var functionOne = function() {
  var $form = $('#'  + tinyMCE.activeEditor.formElement.id);
  $form = $form.append('<input type = hidden name = "authenticity_token" value = "<%= form_authenticity_token %>">')
  var action = $form.attr('action')
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: action,
    data: $form.serialize(),
    dataType: 'script',
  });
};
```

Comment: Chakreshwar, thanks a lot for your answer. I used previously Aniket's approach and it worked. I like the idea of appending the hidden field in the Ajax request to make it neater although it didn't work. Maybe I'm not appending exactly in the last filed or something. I tried to prepend as well without success. Fortunately is working now anyways. Thanks